# Trying to find information on how to build a simple file version controll system

Tags: file

Im want to build a file system for non-tecks( dont care about old versions of the file so no merging or svn/git). The thougt is that a user should be able to download a file, in the same instance the file should be locked for other users. When the first user is done editing the, the file should then automaticaly upload to the server. When he closes the file, the lock should den be opend.

Is this even possible? Im thingking a sort of browser plugin, but I cant find anywone that has done the same thing. (besides microsoft, but who want to go down that road)

Answer (score 0):

That would be: Sharepoint, Alfresco, (almost every WIKI), ...

Actually that is a basic feature of most document management systems. Even SVN has that already and IIRC you can set that up with mod_dav_svn without a line of code (considering configuration is not code).

Also the interesting question is, IMHO, not `TheHappyCase` where the described unit of work goes well but what about this*:

1. **I** Checkout 50 random documents **you** need
2. (get some popcorn and wait for your stresslevel to go up)
3. ?????
4. I get bored and forget about it (everything still being checked out)

*: Points (1) and (2) may change order